# In clojure, what is the exact behaviour of identical?

Tags: clojure, sequence, identity, lazy-sequences

I am very surprised by the behaviour of `identical?` in `clojure`.

`(def a (map identity [:a :b]))
(identical? (rest a) (rest a)); false`

Any idea why `identical?` returns false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`identical?`](http://grimoire.arrdem.com:3000/1.6.0/clojure.core/identical_QMARK/):

```
Tests if 2 arguments are the same object
```

Since `rest` creates a new seq object on each invocation, its results are not `identical?`. The following, however, is:

```
(def r (rest (map identity [:a :b])))
(identical? r r) ;; => true
```

**Update:** As @mfikes pointed out, `rest` does not always create a new seq. It calls `ISeq.more()` internally which is implemented per seq type and might yield different results for lists, vectors, lazy seqs, etc.:

```
(->> [(map identity [:a :b])
      (vector :a :b)
      (list :a :b)]
     (map #(identical? (rest %) (rest %))))
;; => [false false true]
```

Comment: so what is the suggested way to check if a sequence is the rest of another sequence? I mean, `pointerwise` and not `by-value`

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `(every? true? (map identical? sqa sqb))`? Additionally checking for length equality might be required, though.

Comment: Where is it documented that `rest` creates a new seq?

Comment: While `rest` doesn't create a new seq object in general, it does for this sequence. It doesn't for list literals, for example.

Comment: @mfikes True, I adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`identical?` is the object equality predicate. It returns true if its arguments are the same object/primitive.

Use `=` over `identical?`.

`identical?` is the correct tool when semantics depend on pointer equality, such as testing for an end-of-file sentinel value.

Never use `identical?` to compare Clojure data structures. Even keywords don't guarantee `identical?` behaves correctly.